# CodeCanyon JQuery Gallery on Magento

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, gallery

I purchased a gallery on CodeCanyon that I want to use on Magento. I've googled and tried to do research on how to use javascript on magento, and searched here as well, followed instructions, but it still doesn't work.

This is what I purchased:

http://codecanyon.net/item/final-tiles-grid-gallery/4734090

If you go to Live Preview and scroll down you will see the instructions on it if you want to see the reference and compare to what I did (I don't need infinite scroll). You can also go here for their instructions:

http://final-tiles-gallery.com/index.html

---

What I did was add this code to local.xml

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function() {
    $j('#gallery').finalTilesGallery();});
    </script>

    <action method="addJs"><script>//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js</script></action>
           <action method="addJs">          
    <script>magenthemes/grid/jquery.finaltilesgallery.js</script></action>
```

I put the local.xml file into:

root> app/design/frontend/theme/default/layout

I added the JS files to (and created my own directory called "grid"):

root> js/magentothemes/grid/

I added the CSS files to:

root> skin/frontend/theme/default/css/grid

As for the page itself, i went to the CMS page, edit, and under design i put:

```
    <div id="gallery" class="final-tiles-gallery">
    <div class="ftg-items">
    <div class="tile">&nbsp;</div>
     <div class="tile"><a class="tile-inner" href="{{media url="wysiwyg/EZ6A1359.jpg"}}"> <img class="item" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/EZ6A1359.jpg"}}" alt="" data-src="{{media url="wysiwyg/EZ6A1359.jpg"}}" /> </a></div>
    <div class="tile"><a class="tile-inner"> <img class="item" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/EZ6A1359.jpg"}}" alt="" data-src="{{media url="wysiwyg/EZ6A1359.jpg"}}" /> </a></div>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but if anyone could help me, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Laurens

Answer (score 0):

Change the order to:

```
 <action method="addJs"><script>//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js</script></action>
           <action method="addJs">          
    <script>magenthemes/grid/jquery.finaltilesgallery.js</script></action>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function() {
    $j('#gallery').finalTilesGallery();});
    </script>
```

You are calling jquery functions like `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` when the library is still not loaded . Press F12 and refresh the page to check if there is some error in the browser console.